# Bitcoin-Core Developers sharing e-mail address?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development

I've been looking into the Github commit history of Bitcoin. I have no clue how git works, but interestingly, I'm seeing a number of developers' mail addresses associated with commits of others.

For example, Luke-Jr and Gavin Andresen's account emails have both signed commits under Wladimir's name when I run this command:

```
git log --all --format='%aN,%cE' | sort -u;
```

What gives?

```
... truncated:
Fordy,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Forrest Voight,forrest@forre.st
Forrest Voight,forrest@forrest-laptop.(none)
Francesco 'makevoid' Canessa,makevoid@gmail.com
Francis GASCHET,laanwj@gmail.com
freewil,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
freewil,sean@eternalrise.com
fsb4000,fsb4000@yandex.ru
fsb4000,laanwj@gmail.com
Gaurav Rana,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Gaurav Rana,noreply@github.com
Gavin Andresen,Administrator@.(none)
gavinandresen,gavinandresen@1a98c847-1fd6-4fd8-948a-caf3550aa51b
Gavin Andresen,gavinandresen@gmail.com
Gavin Andresen,git@bluematt.me
Gavin Andresen,laanwj@gmail.com
Gavin Andresen,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Gavin Andresen,morcos@chaincode.com
Gavin Andresen,patrick.strateman@gmail.com
Gavin Andresen,pieter.wuille@gmail.com
Gavin Andresen,tcatm@gawab.com
Geoffrey Tsui,tsui.geoffrey@gmail.com
Giel van Schijndel,me@mortis.eu
Giuseppe Mazzotta,gdm85@users.noreply.github.com
gjs278,root@Gentoo.(none)
gladoscc,admin@glados.cc
gladoscc,elacoin@glados.cc
Glenn Willen,gwillen@nerdnet.org
globalcitizen,walter@pratyeka.org
gmaxwell,gmaxwell@gmail.com
graingert,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
graingert,tagrain@gmail.com
Greg Griffith,cryptounitedteam@gmail.com
Gregory Maxwell,falke.marco@gmail.com
Gregory Maxwell,gavinandresen@gmail.com
Gregory Maxwell,git@bluematt.me
Gregory Maxwell,gmaxwell@gmail.com
Gregory Maxwell,greg@xiph.org
Gregory Maxwell,laanwj@gmail.com
Gregory Maxwell,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Gregory Maxwell,pieter.wuille@gmail.com
Gregory Sanders,btcdrak@gmail.com
Gregory Sanders,dev@jonasschnelli.ch
Gregory Sanders,gsanders87@gmail.com
Gregory Sanders,laanwj@gmail.com
Greg Walker,greg@learnmeabitcoin.com
grimd34th,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
grimd34th,ubpd34th@gmail.com
gubatron,gubatron@gmail.com
Guillermo Céspedes Tabárez,laanwj@gmail.com
Haakon Nilsen,haakonn@gmail.com
HaltingState,haltingstate@gmail.com
Hampus Sjöberg,hampus.sjoberg@gmail.com
Han Lin Yap,codler@gmail.com
Han Lin Yap,laanwj@gmail.com
harry,harrywu@tvunetworks.com
HarryWu,imharrywu@users.noreply.github.com
Heath,heathmatlock@gmail.com
Hector Jusforgues,contact@hectorj.net
himynameismartin,himynameismartin@gmail.com
HostFat,matt@bluematt.me
Huang Le,4tarhl@gmail.com
Huang Le,laanwj@gmail.com
Ian Carroll,him@ian.sh
Ian Kelling,ian@iankelling.org
Ian T,hello@chainquery.com
imharrywu,imharrywu@users.noreply.github.com
instagibbs,falke.marco@gmail.com
instagibbs,gsanders87@gmail.com
instagibbs,laanwj@gmail.com
instagibbs,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
instagibbs,pieter.wuille@gmail.com
Irving Ruan,irvingruan@gmail.com
Isidoro Ghezzi,isidoro.ghezzi@icloud.com
isle2983,isle2983@yahoo.com
isle2983,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Ivan Pustogarov,ivanpustogarov@users.noreply.github.com
Ivan Pustogarov,laanwj@gmail.com
Ivo van der Sangen,laanwj@gmail.com
Ivo van der Sangen,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Jack Grigg,jack@z.cash
Jacob Welsh,cory-nospam-@coryfields.com
Jacob Welsh,jacob@welshcomputing.com
Jacob Welsh,laanwj@gmail.com
Jakob Kramer,matt@bluematt.me
James Burkle,james.burkle@gmail.com
James Evans,falke.marco@gmail.com
James Evans,noreply@github.com
James O'Beirne,james.obeirne@gmail.com
James O'Beirne,laanwj@gmail.com
Jameson Lopp,jameson@bitgo.com
Jameson Lopp,jameson.lopp@gmail.com
Jameson Lopp,laanwj@gmail.com
Jameson Lopp,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
James White,james@jmwhite.co.uk
Janne Pulkkinen,jannepulk@gmail.com
Janne Pulkkinen,laanwj@gmail.com
Janne Pulkkinen,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Jannes Faber,noreply@github.com
Janusz Lenar,laanwj@gmail.com
Jaromil,jaromil@dyne.org
Jarret Dyrbye,jarret.dyrbye@gmail.com
JaSK,temp@temp.temp
Jason Lewicki,laanwj@gmail.com
Jay Weisskopf,jay@jayschwa.net
Jeff Garzik,gavinandresen@gmail.com
Jeff Garzik,jeff@bloq.com
Jeff Garzik,jgarzik@bitpay.com
Jeff Garzik,jgarzik@exmulti.com
Jeff Garzik,jgarzik@peernova.com
Jeff Garzik,jgarzik@pobox.com
Jeff Garzik,jgarzik@redhat.com
Jeff Garzik,joao@bitreserve.org
Jeff Garzik,jonas.schnelli@include7.ch
Jeff Garzik,laanwj@gmail.com
Jeff Garzik,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Jeff Garzik,pieter.wuille@gmail.com
Jeff Garzik,sipa@ulyssis.org
JeremyRand,biolizard89@gmail.com
Jeremy Rubin,cory-nospam-@coryfields.com
Jeremy Rubin,jeremy.l.rubin@gmail.com
Jeremy Rubin,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Jeroenz0r,jeroen.marshmallow@gmail.com
Jiaxing Wang,hello.wjx@gmail.com
Jimmy Song,jaejoon@gmail.com
jl2012,jl2012@xbt.hk
JL2035,jl2035@users.noreply.github.com
jloughry,falke.marco@gmail.com
jloughry,joe.loughry@gmail.com
jmacwhyte,keatonatron@gmail.com
jnewbery,falke.marco@gmail.com
jnewbery,john@johnnewbery.com
jnewbery,laanwj@gmail.com
João Barbosa,joao@bitreserve.org
João Barbosa,joao@uphold.com
João Barbosa,laanwj@gmail.com
Joao Fonseca,falke.marco@gmail.com
Joao Fonseca,jpdf.fonseca@gmail.com
Joel Kaartinen,jkaartinen@iki.fi
Joel Kaartinen,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
JoelKatz,DavidJoelSchwartz@GMail.com
JoelKatz,pieter.wuille@gmail.com
Joerie de Gram,j.de.gram@gmail.com
Johannes Henninger,blaubaer@gmail.com
Johnathan Corgan,johnathan@corganlabs.com
Johnathan Corgan,laanwj@gmail.com
John Maguire,johnmaguire2013@gmail.com
John Newbery,greg@xiph.org
John Newbery,john@johnnewbery.com
John Newbery,laanwj@gmail.com
Johnson Lau,falke.marco@gmail.com
Johnson Lau,jl2012@users.noreply.github.com
Johnson Lau,jl2012@xbt.hk
Johnson Lau,laanwj@gmail.com
Johnson Lau,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Johnson Lau,noreply@github.com
Johnson Lau,pieter.wuille@gmail.com
Jonas Nick,jonasd.nick@gmail.com
Jonas Nick,pieter.wuille@gmail.com
Jonas Schnelli,dev@jonasschnelli.ch
Jonas Schnelli,falke.marco@gmail.com
Jonas Schnelli,git@bluematt.me
Jonas Schnelli,greg@xiph.org
Jonas Schnelli,joao@bitreserve.org
Jonas Schnelli,jonas.schnelli@include7.ch
Jonas Schnelli,laanwj@gmail.com
Jonas Schnelli,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Jonas Schnelli,morcos@chaincode.com
Jonas Schnelli,pieter.wuille@gmail.com
Jonas Schnelli,russ@yanofsky.org
Jonathan Brown,jbrown@bluedroplet.com
Jonathan Cross,jonathancross@users.noreply.github.com
Jon Lund Steffensen,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
jonnynewbs,john@johnnewbery.com
jonnynewbs,laanwj@gmail.com
Jordan Lewis,jordanthelewis@gmail.com
Jorge Timón,cory-nospam-@coryfields.com
Jorge Timón,face@hmel.org
Jorge Timón,falke.marco@gmail.com
Jorge Timón,jtimon@jtimon.cc
Jorge Timón,pieter.wuille@gmail.com
Josh Lehan,krellan@krellan.net
joshr,joshr@joshr.com
Josh Triplett,josh@joshtriplett.org
J Ross Nicoll,jrn@jrn.me.uk
J Ross Nicoll,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
jtimon,jtimon@blockstream.io
jtimon,jtimon@jtimon.cc
jtimon,jtimon@monetize.io
jtimon,laanwj@gmail.com
jtimon,pieter.wuille@gmail.com
Julian Haight,laanwj@gmail.com
Julian Langschaedel,meta.rb@gmail.com
Julian Yap,jyap808@users.noreply.github.com
Justin Camarena,justin121994@gmail.com
Justin Camarena,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
justmoon,pieter.wuille@gmail.com
Kalle Alm,kalle.alm@gmail.com
Kalle Alm,karljohan-alm@garage.co.jp
Kamil Domanski,kdomanski@kdemail.net
Kamil Domanski,laanwj@gmail.com
Kangmo,kangmo@nanolat.com
Karl-Johan Alm,kalle.alm@gmail.com
Karl-Johan Alm,karljohan-alm@garage.co.jp
Karl-Johan Alm,laanwj@gmail.com
kazcw,greg@xiph.org
kazcw,keziahw@gmail.com
Kaz Wesley,falke.marco@gmail.com
Kaz Wesley,keziahw@gmail.com
Kaz Wesley,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Kefkius,kefkius@mail.com
kevin,bit.kevin@gmail.com
Kevin Cooper,k.coopr@gmail.com
Kewde,noreply@github.com
keystrike,keystrike@gmail.com
Khalahan,pieter.wuille@gmail.com
KibbledJiveElkZoo,KibbledJiveElkZoo@GMail.com
kirit93,kirit.thadaka@gmail.com
kirit93,laanwj@gmail.com
kirkalx,kirkalx@yahoo.co.nz
kiwigb,kiwigb@localhost.localdomain
kjj2,github@jerviss.org
kjj2,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
kobake,kobake@users.sourceforge.net
Koki Takahashi,k.takahashi@sonyged.com
Kosta Zertsekel,zertsekel@gmail.com
Krzysztof Jurewicz,krzysztof.jurewicz@gmail.com
kwaaak,kwaaak@gmail.com
Kyle Honeycutt,coinables@gmail.com
Lake Denman,lake@lakedenman.com
langerhans,max.keller@gmx.com
Larry Gilbert,larry@l2g.to
Lars Rasmusson,Lars.Rasmusson@sics.se
Lars Rasmusson,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
laszloh,laszloh@1a98c847-1fd6-4fd8-948a-caf3550aa51b
Lauda,falke.marco@gmail.com
Lauda,laanwj@gmail.com
Lauda,lauda.m@protonmail.ch
Lawrence Nahum,lawrence@greenaddress.it
leijurv,leijurv@gmail.com
leijurv,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Leviathn,johnny@blockstream.io
lewuathe,lewuathe@me.com
lizhi,noreply@github.com
LongShao007,007longshao@gmail.com
lpescher,lukas_078@yahoo.ca
Luca Venturini,luca@yepa.com
Luke Dashjr,achow101-github@achow101.com
Luke Dashjr,cory-nospam-@coryfields.com
Luke Dashjr,dev@jonasschnelli.ch
Luke Dashjr,falke.marco@gmail.com
Luke Dashjr,gavinandresen@gmail.com
Luke Dashjr,greg@xiph.org
Luke Dashjr,jgarzik@redhat.com
Luke Dashjr,jtimon@jtimon.cc
Luke Dashjr,laanwj@gmail.com
Luke Dashjr,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Luke Dashjr,pieter.wuille@gmail.com
Luke Dashjr,tcatm@gawab.com
Luke,lukem512@users.noreply.github.com
Luv Khemani,luvb@hotmail.com
m0ray,matt@bluematt.me
maiiz,laanwj@gmail.com
maiiz,zhaohaitao@huobi.com
Manuel Araoz,cory-nospam-@coryfields.com
Manuel Araoz,manuelaraoz@gmail.com
Marcel Krüger,zauguin@gmail.com
MarcoFalke,dev@jonasschnelli.ch
MarcoFalke,falke.marco@gmail.com
MarcoFalke,laanwj@gmail.com
MarcoFalke,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Marco,falke.marco@gmail.com
MarcoFalke,morcos@chaincode.com
MarcoFalke,pieter.wuille@gmail.com
Marcos Mayorga,marcos@ncrypt.com
Marijn Stollenga,laanwj@gmail.com
Marijn Stollenga,m.stollenga@gmail.com
Mario Dian,mariodian@gmail.com
Marius Hanne,marius.hanne@sourceagency.org
Mark Friedenbach,btcdrak@gmail.com
Mark Friedenbach,jtimon@blockstream.io
Mark Friedenbach,laanwj@gmail.com
Mark Friedenbach,mark@blockstream.io
Mark Friedenbach,mark@friedenbach.org
Mark Friedenbach,mark@monetize.io
mark,mark@shotgunsoftware.com
Marko Bencun,marko.bencun@monetas.net
Marty Jones,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Marty Jones,noreply@github.com
Masahiko Hyuga,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Masahiko Hyuga,mail@mhyuga.jp
Mathy Vanvoorden,laanwj@gmail.com
Matt Bogosian,cory-nospam-@coryfields.com
Matt Bogosian,laanwj@gmail.com
Matt Bogosian,mtb19@columbia.edu
Matt Corallo,cory-nospam-@coryfields.com
Matt Corallo,dev@jonasschnelli.ch
Matt Corallo,falke.marco@gmail.com
Matt Corallo,gavinandresen@gmail.com
Matt Corallo,git@bluematt.me
Matt Corallo,greg@xiph.org
Matt Corallo,jgarzik@pobox.com
Matt Corallo,jgarzik@redhat.com
Matt Corallo,laanwj@gmail.com
Matt Corallo,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Matt Corallo,matt@bluematt.me
Matt Corallo,matt@mattcorallo.com
Matt Corallo,pete@petertodd.org
Matt Corallo,pieter.wuille@gmail.com
Matt Corallo,sdaftuar@gmail.com
Matt Giuca,matt.giuca@gmail.com
Matthew Bogosian,laanwj@gmail.com
Matthew Bogosian,mtb19@columbia.edu
Matthew English,h1395010@connect.hku.hk
Matthew English,s-matthew-english@users.noreply.github.com
Matthew King,chohag@jtan.com
Matthew King,laanwj@gmail.com
Matthew Zipkin,falke.marco@gmail.com
Matthew Zipkin,Matthew.Zipkin@gmail.com
Matthew Zipkin,pinheadmz@gmail.com
Matthias Grundmann,matthias@glasmail.de
matthias,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
matthias,s.matthew.english@gmail.com
Matt,laanwj@gmail.com
Matt Quinn,matt@mattjquinn.com
Matt,sirmatt@ksu.edu
mb300sd,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
mb300sd,mb300sd@git
mb300sd,mb300sd@github
Meeh,meeh@sigterm.no
mewantsbitcoins,matt@bluematt.me
Micha,cory-nospam-@coryfields.com
Michael Bauer,michael@m-bauer.org
Michael Bemmerl,mail@mx-server.de
Michael,fanquake@gmail.com
Michael,fanquake@users.noreply.github.com
Michael Ford,cory-nospam-@coryfields.com
Michael Ford,falke.marco@gmail.com
Michael Ford,fanquake@gmail.com
Michael Ford,fanquake@users.noreply.github.com
Michael Ford,laanwj@gmail.com
Michael Ford,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Michael Ford,noreply@github.com
Michael Goldstein,michael@bitstein.org
Michael Hendricks,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Michael Hendricks,michael@ndrix.org
Michael Rotarius,michael-rotarius@rotamedia.de
Michagogo,michagogo@server.fake
Michagogo,Michagogo@users.noreply.github.com
Micha,laanwj@gmail.com
Michal Zima,xhire@mujmalysvet.cz
Micha,michagogo@server.fake
Micha,Michagogo@users.noreply.github.com
Midnight Magic,midnightmagic@example.com
Midnight Magic,midnightmagic@users.noreply.github.com
Mikael Wikman,mikael@swedcontent.com
Mike Cassano,mcassano@gmail.com
Mike Hearn,gavinandresen@gmail.com
Mike Hearn,hearn@google.com
Mike Hearn,laanwj@gmail.com
Mike Hearn,mike@plan99.net
Mike Hearn,pieter.wuille@gmail.com
Mikerah,mikerah14@gmail.com
Mike van Rossum,mike@mikevanrossum.nl
Misbakh-Soloviev Vadim A,laanwj@gmail.com
Mitchell Cash,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Mitchell Cash,mitchell.cash@gmail.com
Mitchell Cash,mitchell@fastmail.com.au
Mitchell Cash,mitchell@mitchellcash.com
mrbandrews,bandrewsny@gmail.com
mrbandrews,falke.marco@gmail.com
mrbandrews,git@bluematt.me
mrbandrews,laanwj@gmail.com
mrbandrews,russ@yanofsky.org
mrbandrews,sdaftuar@gmail.com
mruddy,mruddy@users.noreply.github.com
Murch,alszacrel@web.de
Mustafa,mus@musalbas.com
Nathaniel Mahieu,nate@mahie.us
Nick Bosma,nick.bosma@gmail.com
Nick,nikzhavoronkov@gmail.com
Nicolas Benoit,laanwj@gmail.com
NicolasDorier,btcdrak@gmail.com
NicolasDorier,nicolas.dorier@gmail.com
Nicolas Dorier,noreply@github.com
NicolasDorier,pieter.wuille@gmail.com
Nicolas DORIER,pieter.wuille@gmail.com
Nils Schneider,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Nils Schneider,nils@nilsschneider.net
Nils Schneider,nils.schneider@gmail.com
Noel Tiernan,tiernolan@gmail.com
nomnombtc,laanwj@gmail.com
nomnombtc,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
nomnombtc,mastergizmo@arcor.de
ntrgn,laanwj@gmail.com
ntrgn,ntrgnt@gmail.com
ojab,ojab@ojab.ru
olalonde,olalonde@gmail.com
Olivier Langlois,olivier@olivierlanglois.net
osmosis,shen@shen-90X3A.(none)
Otto Allmendinger,otto.allmendinger@gmail.com
ovdeathiam,krystian.maksymowicz@gmail.com
p2k,gavinandresen@gmail.com
p2k,laanwj@gmail.com
p2k,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
p2k,patrick.p2k.schneider@gmail.com
Patick Strateman,patrick.strateman@gmail.com
Patick Strateman,pieter.wuille@gmail.com
Patrick Brown,patrick.arthur.brown@gmail.com
patrick s,patrick.strateman@gmail.com
Patrick Strateman,falke.marco@gmail.com
Patrick Strateman,laanwj@gmail.com
Patrick Strateman,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Patrick Strateman,patrick.strateman@gmail.com
Patrick Strateman,pieter.wuille@gmail.com
Patrick Varilly,dev@gim.name
Paul Georgiou,pavlos1998@gmail.com
Paul Rabahy,PRabahy@gmail.com
Pavel Janík,cory-nospam-@coryfields.com
paveljanik,falke.marco@gmail.com
Pavel Janík,falke.marco@gmail.com
paveljanik,gavinandresen@gmail.com
paveljanik,laanwj@gmail.com
Pavel Janík,laanwj@gmail.com
Pavel Janík,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
paveljanik,Pavel@Janik.cz
Pavel Janík,Pavel@Janik.cz
Pavel Vasin,cory-nospam-@coryfields.com
Pavel Vasin,laanwj@gmail.com
Pavel Vasin,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Pavel Vasin,pavel@vasin.nl
Pavel Vasin,rat4vier@gmail.com
Pavlos Antoniou,antoniou-p@hotmail.com
Pavol Rusnak,laanwj@gmail.com
Pavol Rusnak,stick@gk2.sk
Pedro Branco,branco@uphold.com
Pedro Branco,laanwj@gmail.com
peryaudo,peraudo@gmail.com
Peter Josling,peterjosling@gmail.com
Peter Todd,dev@jonasschnelli.ch
Peter Todd,gavinandresen@gmail.com
Peter Todd,git@bluematt.me
Peter Todd,jtimon@jtimon.cc
Peter Todd,laanwj@gmail.com
Peter Todd,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Peter Todd,patrick.strateman@gmail.com
Peter Todd,pete@petertodd.org
Peter Todd,pieter.wuille@gmail.com
Petter Reinholdtsen,laanwj@gmail.com
phantomcircuit,laanwj@gmail.com
phantomcircuit,patrick@cloudhashing.com
phantomcircuit,phantomcircuit@debian
phelixbtc,github@blockchained.com
phelixbtc,laanwj@gmail.com
Philip Kaufmann,cory-nospam-@coryfields.com
Philip Kaufmann,gavinandresen@gmail.com
Philip Kaufmann,jonas.schnelli@include7.ch
Philip Kaufmann,jonasschnelli@Jonass-MacBook-Pro.local
Philip Kaufmann,laanwj@gmail.com
Philip Kaufmann,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Philip Kaufmann,phil.kaufmann@t-online.de
Philip Kaufmann,pieter.wuille@gmail.com
philsong,laanwj@gmail.com
Pierre Pronchery,khorben@defora.org
Pieter Wuille,btcdrak@gmail.com
Pieter Wuille,cory-nospam-@coryfields.com
Pieter Wuille,dev@jonasschnelli.ch
Pieter Wuille,dexx@bitwatch.co
Pieter Wuille,falke.marco@gmail.com
Pieter Wuille,gavinandresen@gmail.com
Pieter Wuille,git@bluematt.me
Pieter Wuille,greg@xiph.org
Pieter Wuille,james.obeirne@gmail.com
Pieter Wuille,jl2012@xbt.hk
Pieter Wuille,jonas.schnelli@include7.ch
Pieter Wuille,kdomanski@kdemail.net
Pieter Wuille,laanwj@gmail.com
Pieter Wuille,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Pieter Wuille,matt@bluematt.me
Pieter Wuille,pete@petertodd.org
Pieter Wuille,phil.kaufmann@t-online.de
Pieter Wuille,pieterw@google.com
Pieter Wuille,pieter.wuille@gmail.com
Pieter Wuille,sdaftuar@gmail.com
Pieter Wuille,sipa@ulyssis.org
Pieter Wuille,temp@temp.temp
poole_party,james@esixteen.co
practicalswift,laanwj@gmail.com
practicalswift,practicalswift@users.noreply.github.com
Prayag Verma,laanwj@gmail.com
Prayag Verma,prayag.verma@gmail.com
pryds,laanwj@gmail.com
pstratem,patrick.strateman@gmail.com
ptschip,falke.marco@gmail.com
ptschip,laanwj@gmail.com
ptschip,peter.tschipper@gmail.com
Puru,tuladharpuru@gmail.com
randy-waterhouse,kiwigb@localhost.localdomain
randy-waterhouse,kiwigb@yahoo.com
randy-waterhouse,laanwj@gmail.com
randy-waterhouse,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
randy-waterhouse,noone@yodasan
Rav3nPL,rav3n.pl@gmail.com
R E Broadley,falke.marco@gmail.com
R E Broadley,laanwj@gmail.com
R E Broadley,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
R E Broadley,pieter.wuille@gmail.com
R E Broadley,rebroad+github@gmail.com
redshark1802,redshark@gmx.org
regergregregerrge,regergregregerrge@oxymail.de
Ricardo M. Correia,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Ricardo M. Correia,rcorreia@wizy.org
Richard Kiss,him@richardkiss.com
Richard Schwab,mail@richardschwab.de
Richard Schwab,mail@w.tf-w.tf
richierichrawr,richierichrawr@users.noreply.github.com
rion,laanwj@gmail.com
rion,rion@cs.stanford.edu
Robert Backhaus,laanwj@gmail.com
Robert Backhaus,robbak@robbak.com
Robert McLaughlin,robert@sparkk.us
Rob Van Mieghem,gavinandresen@gmail.com
Rob Van Mieghem,laanwj@gmail.com
rodasmith,falke.marco@gmail.com
rodasmith,noreply@github.com
ロハン ダル,rohun-dhar@MN14042102.local
Roman Mindalev,laanwj@gmail.com
Roman Mindalev,r000n@r000n.net
Rose Toomey,laanwj@gmail.com
Rose Toomey,rktoomey@gmail.com
Ross Nicoll,jrn@jrn.me.uk
Ross Nicoll,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Roy Badami,roy@gnomon.org.uk
Ruben Dario Ponticeli,laanwj@gmail.com
Ruben Dario Ponticelli,laanwj@gmail.com
Ruben Dario Ponticelli,rdponticelli@gmail.com
Rubén Darío Ponticelli,rdponticelli@gmail.com
Ruben de Vries,laanwj@gmail.com
Ruben de Vries,ruben@rubensayshi.com
Rune K. Svendsen,laanwj@gmail.com
Rune K. Svendsen,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Rune K Svendsen,runesvend@gmail.com
Rune K. Svendsen,runesvend@gmail.com
Russell Yanofsky,falke.marco@gmail.com
Russell Yanofsky,laanwj@gmail.com
Russell Yanofsky,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Russell Yanofsky,nicolas.dorier@gmail.com
Russell Yanofsky,russ@yanofsky.org
Russell Yanofsky,sdaftuar@gmail.com
Rusty Russell,rusty@rustcorp.com.au
rxl,me@ryanshea.org
Ryan Havar,falke.marco@gmail.com
Ryan Havar,laanwj@gmail.com
Ryan Havar,noreply@github.com
Ryan Havar,rhavar@protonmail.com
Ryan Niebur,ryanryan52@gmail.com
Ryan X. Charles,ryanxcharles@gmail.com
Saivann,laanwj@gmail.com
Saivann,saivann@gmail.com
sandakersmann,cory-nospam-@coryfields.com
sandakersmann,laanwj@gmail.com
sandakersmann,sandakersmann@users.noreply.github.com
sandos,sandos@sanddesk.(none)
Sanjay Ghemawat,gavinandresen@gmail.com
Santiago M. Mola,coldwind@coldwind.org
Satoshi Nakamoto,gavinandresen@gmail.com
Scott Ellis,sje397@gmail.com
Scott Howard,showard314@gmail.com
Scott Willeke,scott@willeke.com
Sergey Kazenyuk,kazenyuk@gmail.com
SergioDemianLerner,laanwj@gmail.com
Sev,git@sevastos.com
Sev,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Shane Wegner,shane-github@csy.ca
shaolinfry,jtimon@jtimon.cc
Shaul Kfir,shaul.kfir@gmail.com
Shawn Wilkinson,laanwj@gmail.com
Shawn Wilkinson,me@super3.org
Shigeya Suzuki,laanwj@gmail.com
Shigeya Suzuki,shigeya@wide.ad.jp
shshshsh,laanwj@gmail.com
shshshsh,shshshsh@sdsdsdfsd.invalid
Simon de la Rouviere,simon@delarouviere.com
Simone Madeo,noreply@github.com
Simon Males,sime@sime.net.au
Sined,nightsbird@gmail.com
sinetek,laanwj@gmail.com
sinetek,pitwuu@gmail.com
sinetek,root@lstar.my.domain
sirius-m,sirius-m@1a98c847-1fd6-4fd8-948a-caf3550aa51b
sje397,sje397@gmail.com
sje,laanwj@gmail.com
S. Matthew English,laanwj@gmail.com
S. Matthew English,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
S. Matthew English,noreply@github.com
s_nakamoto,s_nakamoto@1a98c847-1fd6-4fd8-948a-caf3550aa51b
Spencer Lievens,noreply@github.com
spin,spin@ctwug.za.net
Stanislas Marion,john@johnnewbery.com
Stéphane Gimenez,dev@gim.name
Stephane Glondu,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Stephane Glondu,steph@glondu.net
Stephen,scmorse@colby.edu
Steven,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Steven,noreply@github.com
Stuart Cardall,developer@it-offshore.co.uk
Stuart Cardall,laanwj@gmail.com
Subo1978,shuebbel@gmx.de
Suhas Daftuar,btcdrak@gmail.com
Suhas Daftuar,dev@jonasschnelli.ch
Suhas Daftuar,falke.marco@gmail.com
Suhas Daftuar,git@bluematt.me
Suhas Daftuar,greg@xiph.org
Suhas Daftuar,jl2012@xbt.hk
Suhas Daftuar,laanwj@gmail.com
Suhas Daftuar,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Suhas Daftuar,morcos@chaincode.com
Suhas Daftuar,pete@petertodd.org
Suhas Daftuar,pieter.wuille@gmail.com
Suhas Daftuar,sdaftuar@chaincode.com
Suhas Daftuar,sdaftuar@gmail.com
super3,me@super3.org
Suriyaa Kudo,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Suriyaa Kudo,SuriyaaKudoIsc@users.noreply.github.com
Sven Slootweg,pieter.wuille@gmail.com
svost,ya.nowa@yandex.ru
tailsjoin,laanwj@gmail.com
Takashi Mitsuta,knhn1117@gmail.com
Tamas Blummer,tamas@bitsofproof.com
Tariq Bashir,laanwj@gmail.com
Tawanda Kembo,tawanda@zimstay.com
tcatm,jgarzik@pobox.com
tcatm,tcatm@gawab.com
฿tcDrak,btcdrak@users.noreply.github.com
฿tcDrak,laanwj@gmail.com
Telepatheic,thomas@instantsolve.net
Teran McKinney,laanwj@gmail.com
TheLazieR Yip,laanwj@gmail.com
TheLazieR Yip,noreply@github.com
theuni,gavinandresen@gmail.com
theuni,laanwj@gmail.com
theuni,theuni-nospam@xbmc.org
Thomas Holenstein,laanwj@gmail.com
Thomas Holenstein,thomas.holenstein@gmail.com
Thomas Kerin,afk11@users.noreply.github.com
Thomas Kerin,btcdrak@gmail.com
Thomas Kerin,pieter.wuille@gmail.com
Thomas Snider,tjps636@gmail.com
Thomas Zander,laanwj@gmail.com
Thomas Zander,thomas@thomaszander.se
Timon Rapp,timon@zaeda.net
Timothy Redaelli,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Timothy Redaelli,timothy.redaelli@gmail.com
Timothy Stranex,laanwj@gmail.com
Timothy Stranex,timothy@Timothys-MacBook-Pro.local
tm314159,laanwj@gmail.com
tm314159,tm314159@users.noreply.github.com
Tom Geller,tom@tomgeller.com
Tom Harding,laanwj@gmail.com
Tom Harding,tomh@thinlink.com
Torstein Husebø,laanwj@gmail.com
Torstein Husebø,torstein@huseboe.net
Trevin Hofmann,laanwj@gmail.com
Trevin Hofmann,trevinhofmann@gmail.com
tucenaber,pieter.wuille@gmail.com
tulip,tulip@JBinUp.local
Tyler Hardin,th020394@gmail.com
UdjinM6,cory-nospam-@coryfields.com
UdjinM6,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
UdjinM6,UdjinM6@dash.org
unsystemizer,laanwj@gmail.com
unsystemizer,noreply@github.com
unsystemizer,something@gmail.com
Vaclav Vobornik,git@vobornik.eu
Vegard Nossum,gavinandresen@gmail.com
Vegard Nossum,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Venkatesh Srinivas,jgarzik@pobox.com
Venkatesh Srinivas,me@endeavour.zapto.org
Veres Lajos,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Veres Lajos,vlajos@gmail.com
vhf / victor felder,victorfelder@gmail.com
Victor Leschuk,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Victor Leschuk,vleschuk@gmail.com
Vinnie Falco,vinnie.falco@gmail.com
Virgil Dupras,hsoft@hardcoded.net
Vitalii Demianets,cory-nospam-@coryfields.com
Warren Togami,cory-nospam-@coryfields.com
Warren Togami,gavinandresen@gmail.com
Warren Togami,laanwj@gmail.com
Warren Togami,wtogami@gmail.com
Whit J,laanwj@gmail.com
Whit J,whitj00@users.noreply.github.com
whythat,falke.marco@gmail.com
whythat,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
whythat,yuri.zhykin@gmail.com
Wil Bown,wilbown@users.noreply.github.com
Will Binns,binns@21.co
Will Binns,will@trek.io
William Yager,will.yager@gmail.com
Witchspace,witchspace81@gmail.com
Wladimir J. van der Laan,cory-nospam-@coryfields.com
Wladimir J. van der Laan,cozzlovan@yahoo.com
Wladimir J. van der Laan,dev@jonasschnelli.ch
Wladimir J. van der Laan,falke.marco@gmail.com
Wladimir J. van der Laan,gavinandresen@gmail.com
Wladimir J. van der Laan,greg@xiph.org
Wladimir J. van der Laan,jonas.schnelli@include7.ch
Wladimir J. van der Laan,jtimon@blockstream.io
Wladimir J. van der Laan,jtimon@jtimon.cc
Wladimir J. van der Laan,laanwj@gmail.com
Wladimir J. van der Laan,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Wladimir J. van der Laan,morcos@chaincode.com
Wladimir J. van der Laan,pete@petertodd.org
Wladimir J. van der Laan,phil.kaufmann@t-online.de
Wladimir J. van der Laan,pieter.wuille@gmail.com
Wladimir J. van der Laan,temp@temp.temp
Wladimir J. van der Laan,witchspace81@gmail.com
Wladimir van der Laan,laanwj@gmail.com
wodry,falke.marco@gmail.com
wodry,laanwj@gmail.com
wodry,wodry@users.noreply.github.com
xanatos,laanwj@gmail.com
xanatos,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
xanatos,xanatos@geocities.com
xHire,matt@bluematt.me
xor-freenet,xor@freenetproject.org
Yoichi Hirai,i@yoichihirai.com
Yuri Zhykin,yuri.zhykin@gmail.com
Zak Wilcox,iwilcox@iwilcox.me.uk
Zak Wilcox,laanwj@gmail.com
Zak Wilcox,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
```

Comment: Can you please specify/clarify what is the question? This seems more like a post than a question

Comment: Yea. Why are the bitcoin developers signing with cross-linked names and addresses?

Comment: Fyi, I ran this command to get the e-mails, within the bitcoin github directory:  git log --all --format='%aN,%cE' | sort -u;

Comment: Correct, the command fetches the e-mails. I don't really about the regex in command, but I manually examined the git log where I am not able to spot these pairs.

Comment: I think something different happens when you squash the commits from multiple authors. I encourage you to manually examine the logs to convince yourself

Comment: @G.Maxwell Have you ever considered that all the fake news against Bitcoin may have been manufactured by Ethereum? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/46700/what-are-the-impacts-of-the-ethereum-pre-sale-pyramidal-wealth-distribution-an

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are seeing has nothing to do with git history manipulation nor with blockstream. It is related to your choice of format specifier. You chose to use `%aN,%cE` which means `author name, committer email`. However, in git, the author and the committer are not necessarily the same person. The author is the person who wrote the patch and the committer is the person who actually adds the patch to the repo. This happens in Core with backports. Someone (the author) writes the patch which gets merged into the master branch of the repo. Later someone else (the committer) uses git cherry-pick to pick the specific commits that made those changes and backport them to a previous version to be later released as a new minor version. The nature of git cherry-pick is that the author of the patch is preserved, but the committer becomes the person who performed the cherry-pick. This is what is causing the discrepancy in your list.

An accurate list of authors and emails would be done using

```
git log --all --format='%aN,%aE' | sort -u
```

Running that command gives me the following output:

```
฿tcDrak,btcdrak@users.noreply.github.com
21E14,21xe14@gmail.com
Abraham Jewowich,abuse@loljews.com
accraze,accraze@gmail.com
Adam Brown,adam@deftnerd.com
Adam Weiss,adam@signal11.com
Addy Yeow,ayeowch@gmail.com
adlawren,adlawren010@gmail.com
Ahmad Kazi,plaxton@users.noreply.github.com
aideca,aideca@users.noreply.github.com
Aitor Pazos,mail@aitorpazos.es
Alex B,paraipanakos@gmail.com
Alex Morcos,morcos@chaincode.com
Alex van der Peet,alex.van.der.peet@gmail.com
Alex Waters,AmpedAl@Gmail.com
Alex,alex
Alexander Jeng,alexanderjeng@gmail.com
Alexander Kjeldaas,alexander.kjeldaas@gmail.com
Alexander Regueiro,alexreg@me.com
Alexey Vesnin,serxis@gmail.com
Alfie John,alfie@alfie.wtf
Alice Wonder,github@domblogger.net
Alistair Buxton,a.j.buxton@gmail.com
Allan Doensen,allan@doensen.com
Alon Muroch,alonmuroch@gmail.com
AlSzacrel,alszacrel@web.de
Altoidnerd,allenmajs1@gmail.com
Altoidnerd,altoidnerd.btc@gmail.com
Amir Abrams,AmirAbrams@users.noreply.github.com
Amir Yalon,git@please.nospammail.net
Anders Øyvind Urke-Sætre,andersoyvind@gmail.com
Anditto Heristyo,anditto.heristyo@gmail.com
Andrea D'Amore,anddam@brapi.net
Andreas Schildbach,andreas@schildbach.de
Andrés G. Aragoneses,knocte@gmail.com
Andrew C,achow101@gmail.com
Andrew Chow,achow101@gmail.com
Andrew Chow,achow101-github@achow101.com
Andrew Poelstra,apoelstra@wpsoftware.net
Andrew Poelstra,asp11@sfu.ca
Andrew,achow101@gmail.com
Andrey Alekseenko,al42and@gmail.com
Andrey,al42and@gmail.com
Andriy Voskoboinyk,andriivos@gmail.com
anduck,anduck@users.noreply.github.com
Andy Alness,andy@coinbase.com
Ang Iong Chun,angiongchun@gmail.com
Anonymous,none@anon
Anthony Towns,aj@erisian.com.au
antonio-fr,anferron@gmail.com
APerson241,setup.pyc@gmail.com
ariel,ariel@ficticio.com
Arnav Singh,arnavion@gmail.com
Arne Brutschy,abrutschy@xylon.de
Ashley Holman,dscvlt@gmail.com
--author=Satoshi Nakamoto,satoshin@gmx.com
Awemany,awemany@protonmail.com
ayeowch,ayeowch@gmail.com
azeteki,azeteki@safe-mail.net
b6393ce9-d324-4fe1-996b-acf82dbc3d53,m8r-emkdvd@mailinator.com
Bardi Harborow,bardi_harborow@yahoo.com.au
Ben Holden-Crowther,benhc@live.co.uk
Ben Holden-Crowther,benhc123@users.noreply.github.com
Benedict Chan,bencxr@fragnetics.com
bikinibabe,amberwelch@unomaha.edu
BitcoinPRReadingGroup,gsanders.87@gmail.com
bitsofproof,tamas@bitsofproof.com
Blake Jakopovic,blake.jakopovic@gmail.com
Blitzboom,anon@none
Bob McElrath,bob@mcelrath.org
Bob McElrath,bob_git@mcelrath.org
Brandon Dahler,brandon.dahler@gmail.com
Braydon Fuller,braydon@bitpay.com
Brian Deery,brian@factom.org
Bryan Bishop,kanzure@gmail.com
BtcDrak,btcdrak@gmail.com
burger2,birger.hedman@gmail.com
calebogden,email@calebogden.com
Calvin Owens,jcalvinowens@gmail.com
Calvin Tam,calvinyhtam@gmail.com
cardpuncher,mauron@vmail.me
Carlo Alberto Ferraris,github@cafxx.strayorange.com
Carlos Pizarro,kr105@kr105.com
Casey Rodarmor,casey@rodarmor.com
Cédric Félizard,cedric@felizard.fr
Celil,celil.kj@gmail.com
celil-kj,celil.kj@gmail.com
centaur1,centaur1@users.noreply.github.com
charlescharles,platypode@gmail.com
Chirag Davé,c@chirag.io
Chris Arnesen,chris.arnesen@gmail.com
Chris Beams,chris@beams.io
Chris Gavin,chris@chrisgavin.me
Chris Howie,me@chrishowie.com
Chris Kleeschulte,chrisk@bitpay.com
Chris Moore,dooglus@gmail.com
Chris Stewart,stewart.chris1234@gmail.com
Chris Wheeler,chris@haydenwheeler.com
Chris,chris@vikki-old.(none)
Christian Barcenas,christian@cbarcenas.com
Christian Decker,cdecker@tik.ee.ethz.ch
Christian Decker,decker.christian@gmail.com
Christian von Roques,roques@mti.ag
Christopher Latham,sudosurootdev@gmail.com
Chuck LeDuc Díaz,chuck.leduc@sage.com
Chuck,chuck@borboggle.com
Ciemon,ciemon@gmail.com
cjdelisle,calebdelisle@lavabit.com
Clark Gaebel,cgaebel@csclub.uwaterloo.ca
Clinton Christian,Clinton.Christian@me.com
coblee,chocobo@alum.mit.edu
coderrr,coderrr.contact@gmail.com
CohibAA,CohibAA@users.noreply.github.com
Colin Dean,git@cad.cx
constantined,nobody@constantined.com
Corinne Dashjr,corinne+git@dashjr.org
Cory Fields,cory-nospam-@coryfields.com
Cory Fields,theuni-nospam-@xbmc.org
Cozz Lovan,cozzlovan@yahoo.com
crowning-,crowning-@users.noreply.github.com
CryptAxe,cryptaxe@gmail.com
CryptoVote,cryptovote@yandex.com
dabaopku,guocong89@gmail.com
Dagur Valberg Johannsson,dagurval@pvv.ntnu.no
Daira Hopwood,daira@jacaranda.org
Dan Helfman,witten@torsion.org
Dan Loewenherz,dloewenherz@gmail.com
Daniel Aleksandersen,code@daniel.priv.no
Daniel Cousens,dcousens@users.noreply.github.com
Daniel Cousens,github@dcousens.com
Daniel Folkinshteyn,nanotube@users.sourceforge.net
Daniel Holbert,dholbert@cs.stanford.edu
Daniel Kraft,d@domob.eu
Daniel Larimer,dlarimer@gmail.com
Daniel Newton,djpnewton@gmail.com
daniel,arowser@gmail.com
Danube,anon@none
Dave Collins,davec@conformal.com
David A. Harding,dave@dtrt.org
David FRANCOIS,david.francois@webflows.fr
David Griffith,dave@661.org
David Grogan,dgrogan@chromium.org
David Hill,dhill@conformal.com
David Hill,dhill@mindcry.org
David Joel Schwartz,davidjoelschwartz@gmail.com
David Perry,enmaku@gmail.com
David Serrano,dserrano5@dserrano5.es
Dawid Spiechowicz,spiechu@gmail.com
Dean Lee,xslidian@gmail.com
default,default@default-dell.(none)
Denis Lukianov,denis@voxelsoft.com
Derek Miller,Derek701@users.noreply.github.com
Derek701,brainish@gmail.com
Dev Random,c1.github@niftybox.net
devrandom,c1.github@niftybox.net
dexX7,dexx@bitwatch.co
dexX7,ugithub@bitwatch.co
Diego Viola,diego.viola@gmail.com
ditto-b,ditto-b@users.noreply.github.com
ditto-b,nipun.d93+evil@gmail.com
djpnewton,djpnewton@gmail.com
dllud,david.ludovino@gmail.com
Dmitry Smirnov,onlyjob@member.fsf.org
Dominyk Tiller,DomT4@users.noreply.github.com
Don Patterson,d_j_p_3@djp3.net
Doug Huff,mith@jrbobdobbs.org
Doug,doug@bitcoinarmory.com
Doug,joroark@vt.edu
Douglas Huff,mith@jrbobdobbs.org
Douglas Roark,doug@bloq.com
Drak,drak@zikula.org
duanemoody,duane_moody@yahoo.com
Dwayne C. Litzenberger,dlitz@dlitz.net
Dylan Noblesmith,nobled@dreamwidth.org
Earlz,earlz@earlz.net
Elias Rohrer,rohrer@informatik.hu-berlin.de
elichai,elichai.turkel@gmail.com
elkingtowa,elkingtowa@gmail.com
Elliot Olds,elliotolds@gmail.com
ENikS,evgeni@eniks.com
Eric Hosmer,EricJ2190@gmail.com
Eric Lombrozo,elombrozo@gmail.com
Eric R. Schulz,ersmail@gmail.com
Eric S. Bullington,eric.s.bullington@gmail.com
Eric Shaw Jr,ericshaw.linux@gmail.com
Eric Shaw,ericshaw.linux@gmail.com
Eric Shaw,ericshawlinux@users.noreply.github.com
Eric Swanson,eswanson@alloscomp.com
Erik Mossberg,lingonvecka@gmail.com
error10,error@ioerror.us
Esteban Ordano,eordano@gmail.com
Ethan Heilman,Ethan.R.Heilman@gmail.com
EthanHeilman,ethan.r.heilman@gmail.com
Everett Forth,everett.forth@gmail.com
Fabian H jr.,fabianherediajr@yahoo.com.mx
Fabian Raetz,fabian.raetz@gmail.com
face,face@hmel.org
fanquake,fanquake@gmail.com
fcicq,fcicq@fcicq.net
Federico Bond,federicobond@gmail.com
Federico Faggiano,federico.sk@katamail.com
flack,flack@contentcontrol-berlin.de
Flavien Charlon,flavien@charlon.net
Florian Schmaus,flo@geekplace.eu
Florin,florin@libertv.ro
flower,flower@k1024.de
Fordy,fanquake@gmail.com
Forrest Voight,forrest@forre.st
Forrest Voight,forrest@forrest-laptop.(none)
Francesco 'makevoid' Canessa,makevoid@gmail.com
Francis GASCHET,fg@numlog.fr
freewil,sean@eternalrise.com
fsb4000,fsb4000@yandex.ru
Gaurav Rana,bitcoinsSG@gmail.com
Gavin Andresen,gavinandresen@gmail.com
gavinandresen,gavinandresen@1a98c847-1fd6-4fd8-948a-caf3550aa51b
Geoffrey Tsui,tsui.geoffrey@gmail.com
Giel van Schijndel,me@mortis.eu
Giuseppe Mazzotta,gdm85@users.noreply.github.com
gjs278,admin@garyshood.com
gladoscc,admin@glados.cc
gladoscc,elacoin@glados.cc
Glenn Willen,gwillen@nerdnet.org
globalcitizen,walter@pratyeka.org
gmaxwell,gmaxwell@gmail.com
graingert,tagrain@gmail.com
Greg Griffith,cryptounitedteam@gmail.com
Greg Walker,greg@learnmeabitcoin.com
Gregory Maxwell,gmaxwell@gmail.com
Gregory Maxwell,greg@xiph.org
Gregory Sanders,gsanders87@gmail.com
grimd34th,ubpd34th@gmail.com
gubatron,gubatron@gmail.com
Guillermo Céspedes Tabárez,dev.dertin@gmail.com
Haakon Nilsen,haakonn@gmail.com
HaltingState,haltingstate@gmail.com
Hampus Sjöberg,hampus.sjoberg@gmail.com
Han Lin Yap,codler@gmail.com
harry,harrywu@tvunetworks.com
HarryWu,imharrywu@users.noreply.github.com
Heath,heathmatlock@gmail.com
Hector Jusforgues,contact@hectorj.net
himynameismartin,himynameismartin@gmail.com
HostFat,hostfat@gmail.com
Huang Le,4tarhl@gmail.com
Ian Carroll,him@ian.sh
Ian Kelling,ian@iankelling.org
Ian T,hello@chainquery.com
imharrywu,imharrywu@users.noreply.github.com
instagibbs,gsanders87@gmail.com
Irving Ruan,irvingruan@gmail.com
Isidoro Ghezzi,isidoro.ghezzi@icloud.com
isle2983,isle2983@yahoo.com
Ivan Pustogarov,ivanpustogarov@users.noreply.github.com
Ivo van der Sangen,ivdsangen@gmail.com
J Ross Nicoll,jrn@jrn.me.uk
Jack Grigg,jack@z.cash
Jacob Welsh,jacob@welshcomputing.com
Jakob Kramer,jakob.kramer@gmx.de
James Burkle,james.burkle@gmail.com
James Evans,keystrike@users.noreply.github.com
James O'Beirne,james.obeirne@gmail.com
James White,jamesmacwhite@users.noreply.github.com
Jameson Lopp,jameson.lopp@gmail.com
Jameson Lopp,jameson@bitgo.com
Janne Pulkkinen,jannepulk@gmail.com
Jannes Faber,jannes.faber@gmail.com
Janusz Lenar,malleor@users.noreply.github.com
Jaromil,jaromil@dyne.org
Jarret Dyrbye,jarret.dyrbye@gmail.com
JaSK,temp@temp.temp
Jason Lewicki,lewicki.jason@gmail.com
Jay Weisskopf,jay@jayschwa.net
Jeff Garzik,jeff@bloq.com
Jeff Garzik,jeff@garzik.org
Jeff Garzik,jgarzik@bitpay.com
Jeff Garzik,jgarzik@exmulti.com
Jeff Garzik,jgarzik@pobox.com
Jeremy Rubin,jeremy.l.rubin@gmail.com
JeremyRand,biolizard89@gmail.com
Jeroenz0r,jeroen.marshmallow@gmail.com
Jiaxing Wang,hello.wjx@gmail.com
Jimmy Song,jaejoon@gmail.com
jl2012,jl2012@xbt.hk
JL2035,jl2035@users.noreply.github.com
jloughry,joe.loughry@gmail.com
jmacwhyte,keatonatron@gmail.com
jnewbery,john@johnnewbery.com
João Barbosa,joao@bitreserve.org
João Barbosa,joao@uphold.com
Joao Fonseca,jpdf.fonseca@gmail.com
Joel Kaartinen,jkaartinen@iki.fi
JoelKatz,DavidJoelSchwartz@GMail.com
Joerie de Gram,j.de.gram@gmail.com
Johannes Henninger,blaubaer@gmail.com
John Maguire,johnmaguire2013@gmail.com
John Newbery,john@johnnewbery.com
Johnathan Corgan,johnathan@corganlabs.com
Johnson Lau,jl2012@users.noreply.github.com
Johnson Lau,jl2012@xbt.hk
Jon Lund Steffensen,jonlst@gmail.com
Jonas Nick,jonasd.nick@gmail.com
Jonas Schnelli,dev@jonasschnelli.ch
Jonas Schnelli,jonas.schnelli@include7.ch
Jonas Schnelli,jonasschnelli@Jonass-MacBook-Pro.local
Jonathan Brown,jbrown@bluedroplet.com
Jonathan Cross,jonathancross@users.noreply.github.com
jonnynewbs,jonnynewbs@gmail.com
Jordan Lewis,jordanthelewis@gmail.com
Jorge Timón,jtimon@jtimon.cc
Josh Lehan,krellan@krellan.net
Josh Triplett,josh@joshtriplett.org
joshr,joshr@joshr.com
jtimon,jtimon@blockstream.io
jtimon,jtimon@jtimon.cc
jtimon,jtimon@monetize.io
Julian Haight,github@a.julianhaight.com
Julian Langschaedel,meta.rb@gmail.com
Julian Yap,jyap808@users.noreply.github.com
Justin Camarena,justin121994@gmail.com
justmoon,justmoon@members.fsf.org
Kalle Alm,kalle.alm@gmail.com
Kamil Domanski,kdomanski@kdemail.net
Kangmo,kangmo@nanolat.com
Karl-Johan Alm,kalle.alm@gmail.com
Karl-Johan Alm,karljohan-alm@garage.co.jp
Kaz Wesley,keziahw@gmail.com
kazcw,keziahw@gmail.com
Kefkius,kefkius@mail.com
Kevin Cooper,k.coopr@gmail.com
kevin,bit.kevin@gmail.com
Kewde,code@shadowproject.io
keystrike,keystrike@users.noreply.github.com
Khalahan,khal@bitcoin-contact.org
KibbledJiveElkZoo,KibbledJiveElkZoo@GMail.com
kirit93,kirit.thadaka@gmail.com
kirkalx,kirkalx@yahoo.co.nz
kiwigb,kiwigb@localhost.localdomain
kjj2,github@jerviss.org
kobake,kobake@users.sourceforge.net
Koki Takahashi,Koki.Takahashi@jp.sony.com
Kosta Zertsekel,zertsekel@gmail.com
Krzysztof Jurewicz,krzysztof.jurewicz@gmail.com
kwaaak,kwaaak@gmail.com
Kyle Honeycutt,coinables@gmail.com
Lake Denman,lake@lakedenman.com
langerhans,max.keller@gmx.com
Larry Gilbert,larry@l2g.to
Lars Rasmusson,Lars.Rasmusson@sics.se
laszloh,laszloh@1a98c847-1fd6-4fd8-948a-caf3550aa51b
Lauda,lauda.m@protonmail.ch
Lawrence Nahum,lawrence@greenaddress.it
leijurv,leijurv@gmail.com
Leviathn,johnny@blockstream.io
lewuathe,lewuathe@me.com
lizhi,cqtenq9@gmail.com
LongShao007,007longshao@gmail.com
lpescher,lukas_078@yahoo.ca
Luca Venturini,luca@yepa.com
Luke Dashjr,luke-jr+git@utopios.org
Luke,lukem512@users.noreply.github.com
Luv Khemani,luvb@hotmail.com
m0ray,anon@none
maiiz,maiiz@users.noreply.github.com
Manuel Araoz,manuelaraoz@gmail.com
Marcel Krüger,zauguin@gmail.com
Marco,falke.marco@gmail.com
MarcoFalke,falke.marco@gmail.com
Marcos Mayorga,mm@mm-studios.com
Marijn Stollenga,m.stollenga@gmail.com
Mario Dian,mariodian@gmail.com
Marius Hanne,marius.hanne@sourceagency.org
Mark Friedenbach,mark@blockstream.io
Mark Friedenbach,mark@friedenbach.org
Mark Friedenbach,mark@monetize.io
mark,mark@shotgunsoftware.com
Marko Bencun,marko.bencun@monetas.net
Marty Jones,murtin.jones@gmail.com
Masahiko Hyuga,mail@mhyuga.jp
Mathy Vanvoorden,mathy@vanvoorden.be
Matt Bogosian,mtb19@columbia.edu
Matt Corallo,git@bluematt.me
Matt Corallo,matt@bluematt.me
Matt Corallo,matt@mattcorallo.com
Matt Giuca,matt.giuca@gmail.com
Matt Quinn,matt@mattjquinn.com
Matt,sirmatt@ksu.edu
Matthew Bogosian,mtb19@columbia.edu
Matthew English,s-matthew-english@users.noreply.github.com
Matthew King,chohag@jtan.com
Matthew Zipkin,pinheadmz@gmail.com
Matthias Grundmann,matthias@glasmail.de
matthias,s.matthew.english@gmail.com
mb300sd,mb300sd@git
mb300sd,mb300sd@github
Meeh,meeh@sigterm.no
mewantsbitcoins,anon@none
Micha,michagogo@server.fake
Micha,Michagogo@users.noreply.github.com
Michael Bauer,michael@m-bauer.org
Michael Bemmerl,mail@mx-server.de
Michael Ford,fanquake@gmail.com
Michael Ford,fanquake@users.noreply.github.com
Michael Goldstein,michael@bitstein.org
Michael Hendricks,michael@ndrix.org
Michael Rotarius,michael-rotarius@rotamedia.de
Michael,fanquake@gmail.com
Michael,fanquake@users.noreply.github.com
Michagogo,michagogo@server.fake
Michagogo,Michagogo@users.noreply.github.com
Michal Zima,xhire@mujmalysvet.cz
Midnight Magic,midnightmagic@example.com
Midnight Magic,midnightmagic@users.noreply.github.com
Mikael Wikman,mikael@swedcontent.com
Mike Cassano,mcassano@gmail.com
Mike Hearn,hearn@google.com
Mike Hearn,mike@plan99.net
Mike Hearn,mike@riker.plan99.net
Mike van Rossum,mike@mikevanrossum.nl
Mikerah,mikerah14@gmail.com
Misbakh-Soloviev Vadim A,mva@mva.name
Mitchell Cash,mitchell.cash@gmail.com
Mitchell Cash,mitchell@fastmail.com.au
Mitchell Cash,mitchell@mitchellcash.com
mrbandrews,bandrewsny@gmail.com
mruddy,mruddy@users.noreply.github.com
Murch,alszacrel@web.de
Mustafa,mus@musalbas.com
Nathaniel Mahieu,nate@mahie.us
Nick Bosma,nick.bosma@gmail.com
Nick,nikzhavoronkov@gmail.com
Nicolas Benoit,nbenoit@tuxfamily.org
Nicolas Dorier,nicolas.dorier@gmail.com
Nicolas DORIER,nicolas.dorier@gmail.com
NicolasDorier,nicolas.dorier@gmail.com
Nils Schneider,nils.schneider@gmail.com
Nils Schneider,nils@nilsschneider.net
Noel Tiernan,tiernolan@gmail.com
nomnombtc,mastergizmo@arcor.de
ntrgn,ntrgnt@gmail.com
ojab,ojab@ojab.ru
olalonde,olalonde@gmail.com
Olivier Langlois,olivier@olivierlanglois.net
osmosis,stevenwagner@gmail.com
Otto Allmendinger,otto.allmendinger@gmail.com
ovdeathiam,krystian.maksymowicz@gmail.com
p2k,patrick.p2k.schneider@gmail.com
Patick Strateman,patrick.strateman@gmail.com
Patrick Brown,patrick.arthur.brown@gmail.com
patrick s,patrick.strateman@gmail.com
Patrick Strateman,patrick.strateman@gmail.com
Patrick Varilly,patvarilly@gmail.com
Paul Georgiou,pavlos1998@gmail.com
Paul Rabahy,prabahy@gmail.com
Paul Rabahy,PRabahy@gmail.com
Pavel Janík,Pavel@Janik.cz
Pavel Vasin,pavel@vasin.nl
Pavel Vasin,rat4vier@gmail.com
paveljanik,Pavel@Janik.cz
Pavlos Antoniou,antoniou-p@hotmail.com
Pavol Rusnak,stick@gk2.sk
Pedro Branco,branco@uphold.com
Pedro Branco,pedrobrancolcc@gmail.com
peryaudo,peraudo@gmail.com
Peter Josling,peterjosling@gmail.com
Peter Todd,pete@petertodd.org
Petter Reinholdtsen,pere@hungry.com
phantomcircuit,patrick@cloudhashing.com
phantomcircuit,phantomcircuit@debian
phelixbtc,github@blockchained.com
Philip Kaufmann,phil.kaufmann@t-online.de
philsong,songbohr@163.com
Pierre Pronchery,khorben@defora.org
Pieter Wuille,pieter.wuille@gmail.com
Pieter Wuille,pieterw@google.com
Pieter Wuille,sipa@ulyssis.org
poole_party,james@esixteen.co
practicalswift,practicalswift@users.noreply.github.com
Prayag Verma,prayag.verma@gmail.com
pryds,thomas@pryds.eu
pstratem,patrick.strateman@gmail.com
ptschip,peter.tschipper@gmail.com
Puru,tuladharpuru@gmail.com
R E Broadley,rebroad+github@gmail.com
randy-waterhouse,kiwigb@yahoo.com
randy-waterhouse,noone@yodasan
Rav3nPL,rav3n.pl@gmail.com
redshark1802,redshark@gmx.org
regergregregerrge,regergregregerrge@oxymail.de
Ricardo M. Correia,rcorreia@wizy.org
Richard Kiss,him@richardkiss.com
Richard Schwab,mail@richardschwab.de
Richard Schwab,mail@w.tf-w.tf
richierichrawr,richierichrawr@users.noreply.github.com
rion,rion@cs.stanford.edu
Rob Van Mieghem,rob@vanmieghemcloud.com
Robert Backhaus,robbak@robbak.com
Robert McLaughlin,robert@sparkk.us
rodasmith,rodasmith@users.noreply.github.com
Roman Mindalev,r000n@r000n.net
Rose Toomey,rktoomey@gmail.com
Ross Nicoll,jrn@jrn.me.uk
Roy Badami,roy@gnomon.org.uk
Ruben Dario Ponticeli,rdponticelli@gmail.com
Ruben Dario Ponticelli,rdponticelli@gmail.com
Rubén Darío Ponticelli,rdponticelli@gmail.com
Ruben de Vries,ruben@rubensayshi.com
Rune K Svendsen,runesvend@gmail.com
Rune K. Svendsen,runesvend@gmail.com
Russell Yanofsky,russ@chaincode.com
Russell Yanofsky,russ@yanofsky.org
Rusty Russell,rusty@rustcorp.com.au
rxl,me@ryanshea.org
Ryan Havar,rhavar@protonmail.com
Ryan Havar,ryan@moneypot.com
Ryan Niebur,ryanryan52@gmail.com
Ryan X. Charles,ryanxcharles@gmail.com
S. Matthew English,s-matthew-english@users.noreply.github.com
s_nakamoto,s_nakamoto@1a98c847-1fd6-4fd8-948a-caf3550aa51b
Saivann,saivann@gmail.com
sandakersmann,mkjaerstad@yahoo.no
sandakersmann,sandakersmann@users.noreply.github.com
sandos,sandos@sanddesk.(none)
Sanjay Ghemawat,sanjay@google.com
Santiago M. Mola,coldwind@coldwind.org
Satoshi Nakamoto,satoshin@gmx.com
Scott Ellis,sje397@gmail.com
Scott Howard,showard314@gmail.com
Scott Willeke,scott@willeke.com
Sergey Kazenyuk,kazenyuk@gmail.com
SergioDemianLerner,Sergio.d.Lerner@gmail.com
Sev,git@sevastos.com
Shane Wegner,shane-github@csy.ca
shaolinfry,shaolinfry@protonmail.ch
Shaul Kfir,shaul.kfir@gmail.com
Shawn Wilkinson,me@super3.org
Shigeya Suzuki,shigeya@wide.ad.jp
shshshsh,shshshsh@sdsdsdfsd.invalid
Simon de la Rouviere,simon@delarouviere.com
Simon Males,sime@sime.net.au
Simone Madeo,simone.madeo@gmail.com
Sined,nightsbird@gmail.com
sinetek,pitwuu@gmail.com
sirius-m,sirius-m@1a98c847-1fd6-4fd8-948a-caf3550aa51b
sje,sje3000@gmail.com
sje397,sje397@gmail.com
Spencer Lievens,spencerlievens@users.noreply.github.com
spin,spin@ctwug.za.net
Stanislas Marion,stanislas.marion@gmail.com
Stéphane Gimenez,dev@gim.name
Stephane Glondu,steph@glondu.net
Stephen,scmorse@colby.edu
Steven,steven@sigwo.com
Stuart Cardall,developer@it-offshore.co.uk
Subo1978,shuebbel@gmx.de
Suhas Daftuar,sdaftuar@chaincode.com
Suhas Daftuar,sdaftuar@gmail.com
super3,me@super3.org
Suriyaa Kudo,SuriyaaKudoIsc@users.noreply.github.com
Sven Slootweg,info@sven-slootweg.nl
svost,ya.nowa@yandex.ru
tailsjoin,tailsjoin@users.noreply.github.com
Takashi Mitsuta,knhn1117@gmail.com
Tamas Blummer,tamas@bitsofproof.com
Tariq Bashir,tariqbashir@gmail.com
Tawanda Kembo,tawanda@zimstay.com
tcatm,tcatm@gawab.com
Telepatheic,thomas@instantsolve.net
Teran McKinney,sega01@go-beyond.org
TheLazieR Yip,thelazier@gmail.com
theuni,theuni-nospam@xbmc.org
Thomas Holenstein,thomas.holenstein@gmail.com
Thomas Kerin,afk11@users.noreply.github.com
Thomas Snider,tjps636@gmail.com
Thomas Zander,thomas@thomaszander.se
Timon Rapp,timon@zaeda.net
Timothy Redaelli,timothy.redaelli@gmail.com
Timothy Redaelli,tredaelli@redhat.com
Timothy Stranex,timothy@Timothys-MacBook-Pro.local
tm314159,tm314159@users.noreply.github.com
Tom Geller,tom@tomgeller.com
Tom Harding,tomh@thinlink.com
Torstein Husebø,torstein@huseboe.net
Trevin Hofmann,trevinhofmann@gmail.com
tucenaber,tucenaber@gmail.com
tulip,tulip@JBinUp.local
Tyler Hardin,th020394@gmail.com
UdjinM6,UdjinM6@dash.org
UdjinM6,UdjinM6@users.noreply.github.com
unsystemizer,something@gmail.com
unsystemizer,unsystemizer@users.noreply.github.com
Vaclav Vobornik,git@vobornik.eu
Vegard Nossum,vegard.nossum@gmail.com
Venkatesh Srinivas,me@endeavour.zapto.org
Veres Lajos,vlajos@gmail.com
vhf / victor felder,victorfelder@gmail.com
Victor Leschuk,vleschuk@gmail.com
Vinnie Falco,vinnie.falco@gmail.com
Virgil Dupras,hsoft@hardcoded.net
Vitalii Demianets,vitalii@orsoc.se
Warren Togami,wtogami@gmail.com
Whit J,whitj00@users.noreply.github.com
whythat,yuri.zhykin@gmail.com
Wil Bown,wilbown@users.noreply.github.com
Will Binns,binns@21.co
William Yager,will.yager@gmail.com
Witchspace,witchspace81@gmail.com
Wladimir J. van der Laan,laanwj@gmail.com
Wladimir van der Laan,laanwj@gmail.com
wodry,wodry@users.noreply.github.com
xanatos,xanatos@geocities.com
xHire,xhire@mujmalysvet.cz
xor-freenet,xor@freenetproject.org
Yoichi Hirai,i@yoichihirai.com
Yuri Zhykin,yuri.zhykin@gmail.com
Zak Wilcox,iwilcox@iwilcox.me.uk
zathras-crypto,zathrasc@gmail.com
ロハン ダル,rohun-dhar@MN14042102.local
```

As you can see, there isn't any of the duplication or discrepancy that you posted about. The duplication here comes from different spellings/versions of people's names (e.g. I use Andrew Chow, Andrew C, achow101, or Andrew) and from the same person using different emails.